# Grid in table HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, pdf, grid

I need help, I have a document that I need to generate in HTML CSS then that will be transformed into PDF.

I have a table to do by putting information like below (the color is not important) :

[image]

Can we put the grid directly in a tag, maybe like that?

```
// example
<td class="grid">
  <p>
   ...text
  </p>
</tp>
```

I have tried different ways but I can't get the results I wanted.

Comment: Please add at least on of your "different ways" to the question. We need more information. What is your actual problem? What do you mean by grid? The css-layout mechanism?

Comment: @lupz I wanted to use a grid, which allows me to separate the information in 2 columns as in the image, because it seems more logical to me. However I did not have all the right css attributes in my possession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will apply 2 columns on one row

add `.grid-container` to the `td`,

and `col1` and `col2` to each `P` under the container

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "col1 col2";
}

.col1 { grid-area: col1; }

.col2 { grid-area: col2; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to put the ```grid-area```  attributes on y ```<p>```, but it works, thanks!